# Why do Sephardi jews put on the tefillin shel yad while sitting?

Tags: tefilin, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, standing-sitting

Pretty straight forward--why do Sephardim put on the tefillin shel yad while sitting?

Comment: You could make this question more valuable by including information about how you know that this is the case (source?) and why you consider it remarkable (contrast with others' practice? known reason for others' practice?).

Comment: possible duplicate of [bracha on tefillin while sitting](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15426/bracha-on-tefillin-while-sitting)

Answer (score 4):

Yalkut Yosef 25:69 says that it is done that way Al Pi Kabala.

> מנהגינו על פי הקבלה להניח תפילין של יד מיושב, ותפילין של ראש מעומד.
>   ומנהג האשכנזים להניח בין תפילין של יד בין תפילין של ראש מעומד.
>   [ילקו''י על תפילין מהדורת תשס''ד, סימן כה הערה סח, שאר''י חלק א' עמ'
>   שנב].

Comment: An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Al Pi Kabala means it is for a Kabilistic reason, which is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: Why in this case we go according to kabbalah and in others we don't?

Comment: Your question was why - which I answered. If you want to ask why in this case we go according to kabbalah and in others we don't, then please [click here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: The Mishna Brurah brings the rule of halacha vs kabbalah in this halacha

Comment: @Sam: Yalkut Yosef disagrees with the Mishna Berura in this case.

Comment: @gershon gold the Mishna Brurah 42 brings the Magen Avraham who leans to sitting and the Kenesses Gedola brings the rules that when kabbalah contradicts halacha ,halacha prevails but when kabbalah is machmir we follow but can't force in case when it is not mentioned in shas and poskim

Comment: @Ramin Also see the discussion [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3826/3) for some relevant suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure an answer that isn't informative is really complete. He's totally justified for seeking clarification here in the comments, such as why suddenly we use Kabbalah.

Comment: [Ben Ish Hai, Wayera I:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14054&st=&pgnum=21) states that a source for this custom from the *Mequbalim* cannot be found in the works of HaAR"I HaQadosh.

Comment: Yalqut Yosef, Siman 25, Note 68 writes that the source for this custom can be found in the [Zohar HaQadosh, Parashat Hayei Sarah, Page 132](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01776_part_5.html#HtmpReportNum0021_L2) beginning with "תָּא חֲזֵי, צְלוֹתָא דְבַר נָשׁ מְעוֹמֶד..."

Comment: @AniYodea "Why in this case we go according to kabbalah and in others we don't?" Others are discussing this, but I'll just add: I have never seen so much kabbalah in any section of halacha as I am seeing now in Hilchos Tefillin uMezuzos. The Beit Yosef and other poskim are quoting the Zohar and other kabbalistic sources constantly.

Answer (score 2):

Hacham Ovadia Yosef has a rule in his Pesakim- "Bimkom Minhag Lo Amrinan Kibalnu Horaot Maran- when there is a preexisting Minhag we don't follow Maran". Why is this so? Because Maran writes in the Hakdama to the Bet Yosef that he didn't come to get rid of old Minhagim. Therefor the preexisting Minhag before the Bet Yosef was to place them sitting down.

Comment: Are you http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1035/hacham-gabriel or do you guys just have the same name?

Comment: @WAF I am him but I lost access to that email. I'm not sure how to get back into that account.

Comment: @msh210 \@monicacellio \@doubleaa Can someone help this man out?

Comment: @hachamgavriel please use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to contact the team about this.  If you can provide them with enough identifying information about the other account they might be able to help you get back in.  (That's not something mods can do; you have to ask them.)